# Coroutine JobCancellationException on updating Firestore document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

Upon calling my ViewModel's `saveUser()`, the Firebase Firestore document is updated successfully, but the coroutine Job gets cancelled, catching a `JobCancellationException`, and the log `"User #${user.id} saved !"` is never printed. Where does this cancellation comes from and how can it complete instead ?

```
// ViewModel.kt

fun saveUser(user: User) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Repository.saveUser(user)
        Log.d("test", "User #${user.id} saved !")
    }
}

// Repository.kt

suspend fun saveUser(user: User) {
    val documentReference = db
        .collection(USERS_COLLECTION).document(user.id)

    try {
        documentReference.set(user).await()
        Log.d("test", "Good")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("test", "Not good") // catches a JobCancellationException
    }
}
```

Comment: Can  you post `.await()`  extension? Or is it from ktx library?

Comment: Why are you using .await() here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Something* is cancelling the Job, and your coroutine is appropriately cooperating.

It could be that your ViewModel is being cleared, since you are launching the coroutine using `viewModelScope`. The ViewModel should not get destroyed unless its owner (Fragment or Activity) is being destroyed. Are you doing something like trying to call `finish()` on your Activity while this is happening, or performing a Fragment transaction?

Or, it could be that something else in the coroutine context is cancelling the Job due to an error. My guess would be that the call to `documentReference.set(user)` is causing some error, and `await()` is cancelling the job, maybe.

Also make sure your dependencies for Firestore, Jetpack, and the KTX extensions are up to date. This may be a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: The fragment was indeed already destroyed at the time Firestore finishes saving the user !